# VBA events for worksheets that are macro generated

Tags: excel, vba

I relatively new to VBA. Here is what I need to accomplish:

I need code to run when the value of some cells changes in some worksheets. I just learned how to do this using events. 
The problem I'm having is that the worksheets that need the event are not there to begin with, but are generated by a macro. Also, their number might vary depending on the data (i.e. sometimes the macro might generate 3, sometimes 10.. and will rename them using some cell values, so also the names differ every time).

From what I can see, the event that triggers the macro on cell change needs to be coded for the object itself (specific worksheets). Is there a way to do it for worksheets that are macro-generated, and don't exist in the workbook when first opened?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe take a look at the [Workbook.SheetChange event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetchange).

Comment: So far I've just seen examples where the worksheet change event was a worksheet-level event. Great to know that can be placed at the level of the workbook as well. Cheers BigBen!

Answer (score 1):

A tiny trick:

The usual way to add a sheet is to use code like:

```
Sheets.Add
```

which will get you a fresh new sheet, but this new sheet will have no event code associated with it.

Instead create a template worksheet *(called templ)*  and in this template worksheet include all necessary event macros.  Now, instead of `Add`ing a new worksheet, just:

```
Sheets("templ").Copy after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
```

you get a new worksheet, but with all macros attached!

Comment: Thanks so much Gary, I'll give this a shot.

Comment: Just to add an additional permutation onto Gary's answer, you could write a function that 1) creates a new worksheet based on the template sheet, 2) copies the data from the target sheet to the new sheet, 3) deletes the old sheet, 4) renames the new sheet to the same name as the old sheet, 5) moves the new sheet to the same location as the old sheet. In this way, you could in effect 'add' the worksheet code to the page!